# class.tslib_pibase.php not found in my TYPO3 6.2.9

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I want to include PHP code in my TYPO3, I found php_page_content, I installed the extension that I found [here](https://www.web-aktiv.com/blog/tag/page_php_content/) .
The installation went fine, no error, then I cleared my cache.
After addind a PHP content in my page
[image]

Then I got a fatal error saying :

> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required
> '/var/www/clevvermail/typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/class.tslib_pibase.php'
> (include_path='/var/www/my_typo3/typo3/contrib/pear/:.:/usr/share/php')
> in
> /var/www/my_typo3/typo3conf/ext/page_php_content/pi1/class.tx_pagephpcontent_pi1.php
> on line 30

I checked and I found no `class.tslib_pibase.php` in my TYPO3!!! How can I manage this ?

[image]

PS: I tried to use the extension [Page PHP Content Element](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/pe_pagephpcontentelement) but it didn't work for me, I install and I find no PHP script in the content list to include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the solution [here](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/54144)

In your ***class.tx_pagephpcontent_pi1.php on line 30***

You can replace this

```
require_once(PATH_tslib . 'class.tslib_pibase.php');
```

By

```
if (!class_exists('tslib_pibase')) require_once(PATH_tslib . 'class.tslib_pibase.php');
```

This works for both Typo3 4.x and 6.2

Comment: I want to say that you should not use or relay on this extension. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I had no other solution to use PHP, the official extension didn't work as I described. Plus I am the only user of the backend.

Comment: I go with Thomas. Whenever you have to execute php code, don't use such extensions. You can't use this in in actual and coming LTS versions and have to begin from the start to get your php code working again. Setting up a small extension is the best way and needs only a few minutes and only a few files. but you can benefit in many points: Using template files to split php/html for better coding and more readability for the written code, add later more or complex code like functions, classes, or database tables, you can update your TYPO3 and your code works in later version like 7, 8 or 9 LTS.

Comment: I totally agree but I am a bit beginner to create an extension. So that was the best-so far- solution for me

Answer (score 0):

I think that the extension is outdated and no compatible with TYPO3 6.2. 
It gives no error just because in the file ext_emconf.php there is no constraint about the CMS version (!)

About the other extension you cited: I was able to make it work with these steps (TYPO3 6.2.30:

1. Install Extension
2. TS Setup > edit whole template record > include static from extension > include "Page PHP Content Element
       (pe_pagephpcontentelement)"
3. Create a Sysfolder (like "phpscripts")
4. go to "phpscripts" > list view > create new > "Page PHP Content Element > P H P Content"
5. insert some code (like the  one you provided) and save
6. go to a page > create new content element > tab "Plugins > "General
   plugin"
7. After you insert the element, edit it, tab "Plugin" > from the
   "selected plugin" dropdown, select "Page PHP content"
8. Tab Behavior > Record storage page > select the sysfolder
   "phpscripts"
9. Save and preview

I am sorry, but I was not able to figure out how to select a single record from the sysfolder :(

Answer (score 0):

You can install the extension **migration_core** or the extension compatibility6.
migration_core contains a Migrations/Code/ folder with class alias mappers. Every reference to the class "tslib_pibase" will be automatically referred to "\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Plugin\AbstractPlugin::class". It is sufficient to have it installed. However compatibility6 is not recommended, because it also contains other changes which have drawbacks.

If you still have the same error message, then open the **TYPO3 Install Tool first tab "Important actions"**.

```
Dump Autoload Information
[Create autoload information for extensions]
```

This (re-)dumps autoload information for all active third party extensions.